# As a pool operator how can I setup having my pool payouts be mined with a 0 fee?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory

I was just wondering because some people talk about mining my pool payout transaction in a block with a 0 fee. How would someone go about doing this properly?

Comment: A 0 fee transactions would be invalid by Monero protocol. You might be able to make your set up work with a very low fee but if there is none your block will be invalid.

Comment: No, that's not true. Fees aren't related to consensus. The software has certain things in place that prevent 0-fee txs from being relayed by nodes, but a miner can mine one all he/she wants. Besides, if they are mining their own tx, it doesn't even matter - they get the fee back anyway.